# socket error: a bytes-like object is requieres, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

estoy tratando de hacer un chat en modo local utilizando socket pero me lanza el error cuando ingreso el mensaje a enviar :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\2.py", line 8, in <module>
    s.send(mensaje,'rb')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

codigo servidor.py:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("",9999))
s.listen(1)

sc,addr = s.accept()

while True:
    recibido = sc.recv(1024)
    if recibido == 'close':
        break
    print(str(addr[0])+" dice: ",recibido)
    sc.send(recibido)
print("adios")
sc.close()
s.close()
```

cliente.py:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('192.168.8.100',9999))

while True:
    mensaje = input("Mensaje a enviar: ")
    s.send(mensaje,'rb')
    if mensaje == "close":
        break
print("adios")
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisamos la documentación de [`send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send), vemos que la definición dice `ssocket.send(bytes[, flags])`, es decir, el método espera un objeto `bytes` no un `str`. Puedes modificar esta llamada:

```
s.send(mensaje,'rb')
```

Por:

```
s.send(mensaje.encode(),'rb')
```

[`encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) es un método de la clase `str` y retorna los bytes correspondientes a la cadena en la codificación pasada por parámetro, en este caso, se usa el default: `utf-8`.

Por último te cometo que [`recv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) también retorna un objeto `bytes` por lo que la forma correcta de hacer la comparación sería usando [`decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), un método en este caso del objeto `bytes`, igual que en el caso anterior, al no indicar nada se usará en el encoding `utf-8` :

```
if recibido.decode() == 'close'
```